# Developing Mathematica applications with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: packages, system-variables

I create Mathematica application. For example testPrj. Now I want load this application for test. Here is a problem: how can I setup environment for loading my application with simple `<<testPrj`?

First what I try is to add to a `$Path` path of my application. But it should be done every time after loading Mathematica (any notebook).

PS: My application has a custom way and it is better not to change

Comment: You can use [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) to change the path in Mathematica automatically when Mathematica starts up.

Comment: @Pickett where I can find that file?

Comment: @molekyla777 Check out the link I gave you! "Possible locations of init.m include the following...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do something at startup, like adding a path so that *Mathematica* can find certain files, you need to use [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html).